# Import CSV to MySql, if duplicate, update selected values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a csv-file into a mysql-databse and i want the uploadscript to check for duplicates and if it finds any it should update that row, but only selected values. I want it to update all values except "first-seen". the bssid is my unique identifyer. I also got suggestions i should change "addslashes" to some better code, but i don´t know which way is the best to do it, any suggestions?

```
<?php 

//Count ap´s before import
$before = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wifi");
$num_rows_before = mysql_num_rows($before);

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    if ($data[0]) {
    $linesCount ++;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wifi (bssid, channel, privacy, ciper, auth, power, essid, latitude, longitude, first_seen, last_seen) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                '".addslashes($data[10])."' 
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","));

//redirect
header('Location: index.php/ladda-upp?success=1&before=' . $num_rows_before); die;

}

//Catch argument from url
$arg_bef=$_GET['before'];

//Count ap´s after import
$after = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wifi");
$num_rows_after = mysql_num_rows($after);

//Count new rows
$new_rows = $num_rows_after - $arg_bef;

//generic success notice
if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<br><b>Resultat: Din fil har blivit importerad!</b><br><br>"; 

//echo stats
echo "Antal före import - ";
echo "$arg_bef";
echo "<br>";
echo "Antal efter import - ";
echo "$num_rows_after";
echo "<br>";
echo "Antal nya rader - ";
echo "$new_rows";
echo "<br>";
echo "Rader i CSV-fil - ";
} 

//Close connection to databse
mysql_close($connect) ; 

?>
```

Comment: What do you consider duplicate - duplicate key? Then you can use `INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = something, col2 = somethingElse, col3 = ......`

Comment: I use bssid as duplicate key. Solved it using "on duplicate key update...". Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want mysql's `on duplicate key feature`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Make sure you've got a key set on a field that appears in the CSV eg: bssid could probably work.

instead of addslashes() use mysql_real_escape_string() but as no doubt someone will point out mysql_ functions are deprecated and will be removed soon so you should be using at least mysqli.

Comment: Solved it using:
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    bssid = values(bssid),
    channel = values(channel),
and so on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: `REPLACE INTO` will behave exactly like `INSERT INTO`, except that it does an `UPDATE` when a duplicate unique value is encountered.